# How to print an arraylist's contents, not its location?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
for(int i=0;i<ab.list.size();i++)
{
    System.out.print( "Account: "+ab.ba.getCustomer().getAcct()+"\nDate:\n"+c);
}
```

`ab` is a Database object.
`ba` is a bank account object
from which you get getCustomer() and getAcct() methods to return a customer object and the method within it, getAcct(), the account number I'm trying to print for each location.

Now, it says this when I try and print it

> java.lang.NullPointerException

Is that because list only returns pointers?

Comment: Please post enough code for us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: No, it's not "because list only returns pointers" (we usually call them references in Java, and there is no other way to work with objects). One of the following expressions evaluated to `null`: `ab`, `ab.list`, `ab.ba`, `ab.ba.getCustomer()`. The details of your NullPointerException (which you didn't post) will probably tell you what you were trying to access, thus hinting at which one was `null`.

Comment: null pointer exception? the arraylist??

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are working in JPA and forgettten to add the MappedBy attribute in the one to many annotation
Or the entity is new
HTH